# Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler not reading the custom metric of ingress' requests-per-second

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to autoscale a certain deployment depending on the requests per second that are sent to the ingress itself, that's what I get when I send 20RPS using Locust :

`my-django   Deployment/my-django   <unknown>/15   1         5         1          13m`

I've followed the following official documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics

This is my HPA config;

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-django
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - object:
      describedObject:
        apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
        kind: Ingress
        name: my-django
      metric:
        name: requests-per-second
      target:
        type: Value
        value: "15"
    type: Object
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-django
```

We are using GKE with Nginx Ingress controller.

Is there a possible way that maybe the problem is with the config of nginx-ingress?